# How to pass value from formfield into executable JSON

Tags: php, html, json, form-fields

I would like to fill in the textfield on the html and when I click the button, the value of that textfield should automatically be passed onto the value for "name" under `CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS`. How do I do that?

Here is my code:

```php
<?php

$curl = curl_init();

curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
  CURLOPT_URL => 'https://api.example.com',
  CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
  CURLOPT_ENCODING => '',
  CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
  CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 0,
  CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
  CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
  CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => 'POST',
  CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS =>'{
  "name": <<<THIS IS WHERE VALUE FROM FORM SHOULD GO>>>>  
  "price_amount": 1000,
  "price_currency": "usd",
  "order_id": "ID",
}

',
  CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
    'x-api-key: <api key>',
    'Content-Type: application/json'
  ),
));

$response = curl_exec($curl);

curl_close($curl);
echo $response;
?>



 
<!DOCTYPE html>  
<html>  
<head>  
         
         
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:400,700">
  <title></title>  
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"></script>
      </head>  
      <body>  
           <div class="container" style="width:500px;">  
                <h4 align="">User Details</h4><br />                 
                <form method="post">  
                     
                     <label>Name</label>  
                     <input type="text" name="name" class="form-control" /><br />
                     <br /><br />                       
                     <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit" class="btn btn-info" /><br />                      
                </form>  
           </div>  
           <br />  
      </body>  
 </html>
```

I want the value from the text form field in html to be added in the executing JSON array.

Comment: The value you are currently passing for CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, is nothing but a text literal. Are you saying you don't know how to concatenate a variable into a string ...?

Comment: And you _should_ rather not be using a text literal there in the first place. Instead, populate the PHP data structure that corresponds to this JSON, and then use `json_encode` to _create_ the JSON representation of that data structure.

Comment: If you don't know how to read the submitted values from a form into a variable using php, there are millions of tutorials online which can show you. It's unclear precisely where you have got stuck, though. P.s. "executable JSON" makes no sense. JSON is a text based data format, not executable code. I realise that probably isn't what you meant, but try to be careful with terminology to avoid confusing people about your intentions

Comment: What is `executable JSON`?

Comment: How do I populate the PHP data structure that corresponds to this JSON, and then use json_encode to create the JSON representation of that data structure?! Can someone give me a sample code I can work from...

Comment: You make an object or array like `$arr = ["prop1" => "val1", "prop2" => 25]; $json_encode($arr);`. Obviously you can use variables to populate the bits of the php array as needed. But really...did you need another example? Are search engines banned in your location? Is the php manual inaccessible? We're happy to help people if necessary, but we try to avoid repeating things you can easily google already